# Transfer Comodo Security Certificate from PC to Android

Tags: security, ca

Over the last couple of days, I have been trying to update the keystore on my Samsung Galaxy Tab running Android 2.2. My company recently updated their Citrix server apps (XenApp to be more specific) and also changed their security certificate from CA to Comodo.

I've tried everything from manually loading the certificate to using Java and BouncyCastle to put the certificate into the cacerts.bks file from my tablet to using Portecle to try and create a new bks file. None of those options have worked so far.

The one thing I have not tried and am willing to try if necessary is pulling the cacerts.bks file from my phone which is running Android 4.1.1 but didn't want to run the risk of it not working. (Not sure if it is still cacerts.bks on 4.1.1)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If all I've needed to do is move the cacerts.bks file from my phone to my tablet I'm probably just going to bash my head against the desk for the next couple of days.

Thank you all!

Joe